# fgetcsv insert values order by $fileop

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fgetcsv

I have a CSV file with 3 columns **lastname, firstname, matricule** and I would like to import them with order by **matricule**

Currently I have this working PHP code:

```
$query = "TRUNCATE TABLE `personnal` ";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        while (($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {

            $lastname = $fileop[0];
            $firstname = $fileop[1];
            $matricule = $fileop[2];
            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO personnal (lastname,firstname,matricule,usermaj) VALUES ('$lastname','$firstname','$matricule','importCSV')");
        }
```

I tried to add `ORDER BY $matricule` but it was too easy to work.

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO personnal (lastname,firstname,matricule,usermaj) VALUES ('$lastname','$firstname','$matricule','importCSV') ORDER BY '$matricule'");
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY' at line 1(errno)

We will import every week this kind of CSV file and I need to have the auto AI id to be the same all the time. Mister X cannot be one week id=61 and next week id=63.
If `ORDER BY '$matricule'` during the importation is possible it should solve my problem. Otherwise I have to do it manualy while converting it to CSV.

Comment: Apply ORDER BY to SELECT statements, not to INSERTs

Comment: But don't rely on an autoincrement id for ordering records, it only guarantees uniqueness not order

Comment: @MarkBaker sure i always do that excepted this time i need it to be stored already ordered BY matricule. I'm not sure its possible.

Comment: It should be possible if you use [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) with REPLACE and matricule is a unique key

Comment: @MarkBaker Sounds a bit complicated. I will study a bit how i can adapt it with my current PHP code. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finaly come up to the idea an unique ID like MD5 is the best. I also need history so I removed `TRUNCATE table`

**Solution :**

```
$personnal_id = md5($lastname.$fistname);

            $resultpersonnal_id = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM personnal WHERE personnal_id='$personnal_id'");
            $number=mysql_result($resultpersonnal_id, 0, 'number');



            if ($number == 0) {
                $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO personnal (personnal_id,lastname,firstname,matricule,usermaj) VALUES ('$personnal_id','$lastname','$firstname','$matricule','importCSV')");

            }
```